# Pyspark conditional fill a column

Tags: pyspark

I want to make a column `id1` in `ss_df` such that if length of `id` is 13, then take substring from 6th digit to end of digits; else when length of `id` is 9 take the substring from the 3rd digit to the end.
How do I achive this using pyspark?
`ss_df` :

| id | id1 |
| --- | --- |
| 9999945678909 | 45678909 |
| 789065437 | 9065437 |
| 67898095 | 67898095 |

What I tried :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import length

if (length(col("id")) == 13):
  ss_df = ss_df.withColumn("id1", substring("id",6,15))
if (length(col("id")) == 9):
  ss_df = ss_df.withColumn("id1", substring("id",3,15))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyspark functions provide utility **when** in the following manner to create and populate column conditionally

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([("abcde", 1), ("abc", 2), ("a", 3)], ["value", "r"])
>>> df = df.withColumn('id', F.when(F.length(df.value) == 3, F.substring(df.value, 1, 10)).otherwise(F.when(F.length(df.value) == 5, F.substring(df.value, 2, 10)).otherwise(None)))
>>> df.show()
+-----+---+----+                                                                
|value|  r|  id|
+-----+---+----+
|abcde|  1|bcde|
|  abc|  2| abc|
|    a|  3|null|
```

Note: In Function F.substring(Col, index, len), index is not 0 based but 1 based index.

Comment: I do not want `null`  for other conditions if those 2 conditions are not satisfied , I want the same value as `value` .( from the example `df` you have taken)

Comment: There you can use the df.value instead of None.